# add class to element when content loads angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to add a class to the `.container` element when the content loads of an angularjs app:

Part of my code is as follows, how can I do this, not sure how it's done?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container " ng-view>
..
```

**JS**

```
**app.controller('ShowImages', function($scope, InstagramAPI){
    $scope.layout = 'grid';
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.pics = [];


    InstagramAPI.fetchPhotos(function(data){
      $scope.pics = data;
      console.log("length is "+data.length)
    });
  });**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

```
<div class="container" data-ng-class="{ 'yourcustomclass': pics.length > 0 }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this :

```
<div class="container" ng-class="{'customclass' : pics.length > 0}"></div>
```

Comment: I get a console error when adding that: http://machinas.com/wip/machinas/instagramfeed/